# Modificar estilos de un componente en Ionic 5 y angular 7

Tags: angular7, ionic-framework, scss, ionic4

Estuve leyendo sobre el tema. Según entendí angular agrego una funcionalidad que hace que se encapsulen los estilos de un componente. No entendí bien como funciona esto. Pero entendí que para referir a los estilos del componente hay dos formas:

Ayer pregunte esto pero era demasiado tarde por lo que no tuve respuestas.

```
:host{
  ion-content {
    background: red;
  }
}

// O esta otra forma

page-name{
    ion-content{
       background: red;
    }
}
```

Mi problema es que directamente no me funciona. Siempre tengo que hacer lo siguiente.

```
:host{
  ion-content {
    --background: red;
  }
}
```

De esta forma si se toman los estilos. Pero se vuelven recurrentes. Por lo que si reescribo los estilos de un componente de ionic, este se aplica para todos los hijos de este componente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código que tengo. Espero me puedan ayudar.

**HTML**

```
<ion-content class="background">
  <ion-card-content>
    <img class="logo" src="assets/logo/579358.svg" alt="">
    <ion-card-header>
      <ion-card-title text-center>Reading the barcode</ion-card-title>
      <ion-card-subtitle text-center>welcome to the your new app</ion-card-subtitle>
    </ion-card-header>
    <form [formGroup]="loginForm">
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label position="floating">
          email
        </ion-label>
        <ion-input formControlName="email" type="text" name="email"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
      <div class="error-messages">
        <ng-container *ngFor="let error of error_messages.email">
          <div class="error-message"
            *ngIf="loginForm.get('email').hasError(error.type) && (loginForm.get('email').dirty || loginForm.get('email').touched)">
            {{ error.message }}
          </div>
        </ng-container>

      </div>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label position="floating">
          password
        </ion-label>
        <ion-input formControlName="password" type="password" name="password"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
      <div class="error-messages">
        <ng-container *ngFor="let error of error_messages.password">
          <div class="error-message"
            *ngIf="loginForm.get('password').hasError(error.type) && (loginForm.get('password').dirty || loginForm.get('password').touched)">
            {{ error.message }}


          </div>
        </ng-container>

      </div>
      <br>
      <ion-button (click)="onLogin()" [disabled]="!loginForm.valid" expand="block" shape="round">
        <ion-icon slot="start" name="contact"></ion-icon>
        Login
      </ion-button>
    </form>
  </ion-card-content>
</ion-content>
```

**SCSS**

```
:host {
    ion-content {
        --background: url("./../../../../assets/App/7243-01-low-poly-background-16x9-1.jpg") !important;
        --ion-background-color: #006ff8 !important;
        background-position: center, center !important;
        background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
        background-size: cover !important;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con lo que pasa con Angular View Encapsulation es que te ayudar en encuapsular los estilos eso quiere decir es que cuando declaras ViewEncapsulation en un componente no cargara los estilos de Angular o Material Bootstrap recuerda que son SPA y que por lo regular si te mueves de componente y tienen el mismo nombre de la clase puede que cargue los estilos de la pagina anterior.

Esto te ayudara a que puedas editar los estilos de un componente si afectar a otros.

```
import {ViewEncapsulation} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-elemplo',
  templateUrl: 'ejemplo.html',
  styles: [],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```